# Nesting components - applying independent styles

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

So I have a react component that I can pass `size` prop to. It can be either `small`, `regular` or `large` and based on the type a css class assigned - they look like this:

```
.my-component {
  &--small-size .column {
    height: 40px;
  }
  &--regular-size .column {
    height: 60px;
  }
  &--large-size .column {
    height: 80px;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I nest those components (see example below), I get the style from the parent (so here to size of nested `MyComponent` will still be `regular` instead of `small` - this is pure CSS problem.

How can this be solved so the nested component always gets independent styles?

```
const Page = (props) => {
  return (
    <MyComponent size="regular">
      {/* Some other HTML elements*/}
      <MyComponent size="small">
        ...
      </MyComponent>
    </MyComponent>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hmm, that should not be possible. Because each is a complete different entity. Could you please share the code of your `MyComponent` component? Check out his [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/61pzjkwmz3):

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order the styles are included.

```
.my-component {
  &--large-size .column {
      height: 80px;
  }
  &--regular-size .column {
      height: 60px;
  }
  &--small-size .column {
     height: 40px;
  }
}
```

In CSS, if the items are of the same specificity, the last item will take precedence.  Since your code is nested small as a child of regular, your CSS should reflect this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually with only css, like this :

```
.my-component {
    &--small-size .column,
    &--regular-size &--small-size .column,
    &--large-size &--small-size .column {
      height: 40px;
    }

    &--regular-size .column,
    &--small-size &--regular-size .column,
    &--large-size &--regular-size .column
    {
      height: 60px;
    }

    &--large-size .column,
    &--small-size &--large-size .column,
    &--regular-size &--large-size .column
    {
      height: 80px;
    }
  }
```

Or fallback to inline style :

```
const small = {height : '40px'};
const regular = {height : '60px'};
const large = {height : '80px'};

const Page = (props) => {
    return (
      <MyComponent style={regular}>
        {/* Some other HTML elements*/}
        <MyComponent style={small}>
          ...
        </MyComponent>
      </MyComponent>
    );
  };
```